# Checking user mouse movement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update my server to let it know that the user had some activity in the past 15 minutes. In order to do that, I made this implementation:

```
var page = {

    updated: false,

    change_state: function(e)   {
        var self = this;
        if(!this.updated){
            debugConsole.log('Moved mouse');
            setTimeout(function(){
                self.updated = false;
            },  //                10000); //10 seconds
                120000); //2 minutes
            this.updated = true;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'comet/update.php',
                success: function(data){
                    debugConsole.log('Moved mouse at: ' + data);
                }
            })
        }
    },

    mouse_click: function(e)    {
        this.updated = false;
    }

}

$("*").live('mousemove',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    page.change_state(e); });

$("*").live('click',function(e){
    page.mouse_click(e); });
```

I made it so that it only takes effect after 2 minutes from the last action, unless the last action was a click.

Is this the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using $("*").live, you only need the events on the document body, so long as they are allowed to properly bubble.

Comment: How do i make the `properly bubble`? this page is live so the dom is changing all of the time

Comment: @Neal — Events bubble unless they are specifically prevented from doing so.  You should be able to use `$(document.body).bind` instead of `$("*").live` (and you will see much better performance if you do).

Comment: @BenBlank, how do i use `document.bind`?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't alert the server every time the mouse moves.  Instead I'd just make a note of the time. For letting the server know I'd set up an interval that tells the server if the user has been active recently.

```
var page = {
    lastUpdated: (new Date).getTime(),
    mouse_move: function(e)   {
        this.lastUpdated = (new Date).getTime();
    },
    mouse_click: function(e)    {
        this.lastUpdated = (new Date).getTime();
    },
    checkForLife: function () {
        if( page.lastUpdated + 15 * 60 * 1000 > (new Date).getTime() ) {
            $.post('comet/update.php',{status: 'alive'});
        } else {
            $.post('comet/update.php',{status: 'dead'});
        }
    }
}
$("body").mousemove( page.mouse_move );
$("body").click( page.mouse_click );
setInterval( page.checkForLife, 2 * 60 * 1000 );
```

Comment: how is this different than what i have?

Comment: 1: The event binding are only on the body. 2: The server interaction is handled in a separate `setInterval`, not an event.

Comment: yes but it happens every `x` seconds as opposed to hen they do the action, why would i want that?

Comment: 1: the posting loop also lets the server know the user is idle. 2: the posting loop is evenly rate limited to balance server load.

Comment: yes, but i dont want to send a message if no action was taken, this app may be for many users, and i dont want a high server hit

Answer (score 1):

The `.live()` has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 we use the `.on()` method now:

```
$("*").on('mousemove',function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    page.change_state(e); 
});

$("*").on('click',function(e){
    page.mouse_click(e); 
});
```

Also I wouldn't recommend attaching an event handler to that global element.